# It gives an error for big values

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime

I am solving a simple question of finding the nth power of 2.It works for lower power of n,but fails when I try doing it for higher powers,also,the question which I have been asked has to % 10^9+7 to reduce the size.
If you could please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
long long int pro=1;

long long int func(int n)
{
if(n!=1)
{   pro=pro%1000000007;
    pro=(2*func(n-1));
 return pro;
}

return 1;
}

int main()
{



    pro=1;
    long long int n=555555;

     long long int x;
    if(n!=1)
  x=func(n);
    else
      x=1;

    cout<<x<<endl;


  }

return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(n!=1){
   x=func(n);
 }else{
      x=1; //this is incorrect, you should return 2.
 }
```

also

```
    long long int func(int n)
    {
      if(n!=1)
      { 
         pro=(2*(func(n-1)%1000000007))%1000000007;
         return pro;
       }
       else return 2;
     }
```